# Parallel computing using Optim in Julia

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, julia

I’m running the program below on a 32 cpu/64 thread system without much of anything else running on it. If I use anything beyond 16 cores then the execution time in the second run is effectively flat. This is true both when I using a precompiled system image and when I don’t (though a bit more so when using a precompiled system image for reasons I don’t understand). What am I missing?

```
using Distributed 
@everywhere using Optim, LinearAlgebra

@everywhere const R = 8000
@everywhere const d = 40

@everywhere function once(x::Int64)
    for r = 1: ((x<0) ? 1 : R)
        function Ω(θ::Vector{Float64})::Float64
            dot(θ,θ) * 0.5
        end
        function dΩ!(g::Vector{Float64}, θ::Vector{Float64})
            g[:] = θ
        end
        function ddΩ!(H::Matrix{Float64}, θ::Vector{Float64})
            H[:,:] .= 0.0
            for i = 1:d
                H[i,i] = 1.0
            end
        end
        Optim.optimize(Ω::Function, dΩ!::Function, ddΩ!::Function, ones(Float64,d), NewtonTrustRegion())
    end
end

function doit()
    @time pmap(once, -64:-1)
    @time pmap(once, 1:192)
end

doit()
```

Comment: Because you measure compilation time in the first run. But I'll let someone else elaborate on that, as I'm not experienced in parallel computing. But as an aside: the Hessian is apprearently just `LinearAlgebra.I`, or at least can be described by `UniformScaling` or `Diagonal`, which will improve multiplication speed, altough you'd have to test whether it's worth giving up inplace updates for it. And the gradient update should prefereably be written as `g .= \theta`.

Comment: I only compare the run times in the second run.  The Hessian is just a holdover from my original code, which I'd scaled down to a MWE: admittedly lazy.  Got an answer on Julia Discourse.  The issue is related to the number of threads OpenBLAS uses.